# mvn clean install fails with error in tests but the test function passes when I run it

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, mockito, powermockito

I have a new project and testing its functions. For that I created a `TestClass` which extends `PowerMockTestCase`. In this class I have several functions that initialize variables (objs) and prepare the inputs for the test. One of the test functions that I have is something like this:

```
      @Test
      public void testWList() throws Exception {
          assertEquals(pageList.size(), 4);
          assertNull(pageList.get(0).getC("176").getN("263").getL().getW());
          Class1 c1 =  Util.merge(pageList, obj1, obj2);
          assertEquals(c1.getC().size(), 6);
          assertEquals(pageList.size(), 3);
          assertNotNull(c1.getC("176"));  
          assertNotNull(c1.getC("176").getN("263"));
---->     assertNotNull(c1.getC("176").getN("263").getW());
          .....
          .....
      }
```

Class1 is a class that includes primitives and also a list of a another class (let's say Class2) which itself has similar structure. for example, getC() gets the list of a class obj which itself has getN() that again gets a lift of another class obj (Class3 for example). Following is getC, getN has exact same structure.

```
   @JsonIgnore
   public Class2 getC(String Id) {
      Class2 retVal = null;

      if (Utils.isNotEmpty(Id)) {
        for (Class2 c2 : List<Class2>) {
            String currId = c2.getZId();
            if (Utils.isNotEmpty(currId)
                    && currId.equals(Id)) {
                retVal = c2;
                break;
            }
        }
      }

       return retVal;
    }
```

When I run the `testWList` function individually it passes all the test cases, but when I try to build the project using (`mvn clean install`) it fails in the line that is identified by an arrow in the above code, `assertNotNull(c1.getC("176").getN("263").getW());`. Following is the error that I see while I run `mvn clean install`:

```
     Running TestSuite
     *** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at JPLISAgent.c line: 844
     *** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at JPLISAgent.c line: 844
     *** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at JPLISAgent.c line: 844
     *** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at JPLISAgent.c line: 844
     *** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at JPLISAgent.c line: 844
     *** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at JPLISAgent.c line: 844
     *** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message 
     transform method call failed at JPLISAgent.c line: 844
     Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: CodeCache is full. Compiler has been disabled.
     Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Try increasing the code cache size using -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
     CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=243187Kb max_used=243262Kb free=2572Kb
     bounds [0x000000010451d000, 0x000000011351d000, 0x000000011351d000]
     total_blobs=66659 nmethods=65908 adapters=612
     compilation: disabled (not enough contiguous free space left)
     Tests run: 2899, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1,084.705 sec <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
     testWList(com.abtest.BBBB.TestClass)  Time elapsed: 0.031 sec  <<< FAILURE!
     java.lang.AssertionError: expected object to not be null at com.abtest.BBBB.TestClass.testWList(TestClass.java:219)


     Results :

     Failed tests: 
        TestClass.testWList:219 expected object to not be null

        Tests run: 2899, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [INFO] Total time:  19:54 min
        [INFO] Finished at: 2021-08-05T22:11:09-07:00
        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project p1: There are test failures.
        [ERROR] 
        [ERROR] Please refer to /Users/aa/p/f/p1/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
        [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
        org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute 
        goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project p1: There are test failures.

        Please refer to /Users/aa/p/f/p1/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
        Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: There are test failures.
```

I don't understand the reason behind this, how come when I run the test it passes but when I do mvn clean install it fails. I need to build it without skipping the tests.

Comment: First what kind of data structure is `c1.getC("176")` accessing? Map? Apart from that when I read powermock in my opinion there is already a basic problem.. Which Java version, Maven Version do you use? The surefire plugin you are using is really old... ?

Comment: it's a list of a class object. Which the class itself has different kinds of fields, including String, Long, List<another_class>, Map and etc. 
Maven home: /Users/aa/apache-maven-3.6.1
Java version: 1.8.0_201, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home/jre

Comment: Where/how are the fields `pageList`, `obj1`, `obj2` initialised? It appears you have multiple testcases. Obviously when ran individually they have access to clean data and underlying fields i.e. `obj1`, `obj2` etc. When you run mvn clean install it will run tests one after the other and will mean obj1, obj2 could be in "dirty" state. You need to try and isolate unit tests to use method level variables or initialise/clean them via setup/teardown methods.

Comment: The access via `c1.getC("..")` means accessing a field ? Which kind of datastructure will be given which you use?

Comment: @Setu, all the inputs `pageList`, `obj1`, `obj2` are all initialized inside the same class but in different functions `@BeforeClass
    public void init() throws Exception ` ...@khmarbaise i added the getC function above.